# Pythagorean Triplets

Tags: code-golf, math

The **[Pythagorean Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)** states that for a right triangle with sides `a`, `b`, and `c`, a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>=c<sup>2</sup>.

A [**Pythagorean triplet**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Pythagorean_triples) is a set of three numbers, where a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>=c<sup>2</sup>, a
To extend this even further, a **primitive Pythagorean triplet** is a Pythagorean triplet where `gcd(a,b,c)=1`.

The goal is to find 100 primitive Pythagorean triplets.

**Input:** No input.

**Output:** 100 primitive Pythagorean triplets, in whatever order and shape, as long as the output contains only those triplets.

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: Is a < b or are  (a,b,c) and (b,c,a) 2 solutions.

Comment: @user unknown: a<b<c

Comment: They're called "triples", not "triplets".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Python, 42

```
i=4
while i<203:print 2*i,i*i-1,i*i+1;i+=2
```

Comment: `i**2` -> `i*i` to save a couple of characters.

Comment: I should mark this as cheating, but oh well. :)

Comment: How is it cheating?

Comment: I was hoping everybody would actually generate the triplets by brute force, but I guess a math formula is fine too. :P

Comment: "hoping for brute force" -- there's something you don't hear every day.

Comment: @beary605 why have you accepted the answer that isn't the shortest?

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript, 44 characters

**Update:**

```
for(i=s=0;i^400;)s+=[i+=4,r=i*i/4-1,r+2]+' '
```

I should have looked up an algorithm first. Well, can't beat python anyway.

Run in a console to see the result.

**Old, slow, brute-force variant (140 characters)**

```
for(q=a=[];563>++a;)for(b=a;--b;)(k=Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b))==~~k==function c(e,d,f){return f?c(c(f,e),d):d?c(d,e%d):e}(a,b,k)&&q.push([b,a,k]);q
```

Answer (score 5):

### J, <strike>64</strike> <strike>60</strike> <strike>38</strike> 49 characters

```
100$}.~.(/:~*(0<*/*1=+./))"1[4$.$.(=/+/~)2^~i.699
```

Should've realised that such a big gain was probably flawed. Still uses the brute-force method, but done a bit more efficiently.

Explanation:

`x=.2^~i.699` generates a list of ints from 0 to 699 and squares `2^~` them (`~` here reverses the order of the arguments).

`(=+/~)` is a hook that generates an addition table and compares the result to the list.  This gives me a three dimensional array with items which are either `1` or `0`. A `1` means that a<sup>2</sup>+b<sup>2</sup>=c<sup>2</sup>.

`$.` converts to a sparse array. For my smaller (9) example I get:

```
   $.(=/+/~)2^~i.9
0 0 0 | 1
1 0 1 | 1
1 1 0 | 1
2 0 2 | 1
2 2 0 | 1
3 0 3 | 1
3 3 0 | 1
4 0 4 | 1
4 4 0 | 1
5 0 5 | 1
5 3 4 | 1
5 4 3 | 1
5 5 0 | 1
6 0 6 | 1
6 6 0 | 1
7 0 7 | 1
7 7 0 | 1
8 0 8 | 1
8 8 0 | 1
```

`4$.` just gives me the left part of this list.

`(/:~*(0<*/*1=+./))"1[` decides which rows meet the criteria. `(verb)"1` tells the verb to act on the individual rows rather than on the list. `[` just separates the `1` and `4`, otherwise J will think that `1 4` is a list of 2 numbers. '1=+./' gets the GCD of the three numbers and checks if it's `1`. `*/` multiplies each triple together (getting `0` if it contains a `0`) and these two are multiplied together. `0<` turns the result into a boolean. `*` multiplies this result by each triple which eliminates all triples which contain a `0` or have a GCD which is not `1`. `/:~` sorts each triple.

`~.` selects the unique items from the list.

`}.` removes the first item (0 0 0) from the list.

`100$` takes the first 100 items from the list.

The above is my answer to this question, but as a matter of interest I implemented [grc's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6447/737), (27 characters):

```
2(*,.<:@^~,.>:@^~)2*2+i.100
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala 180:

```
def g(a:Int,b:Int):Int=if(a==b)a else
if(a>b)g(a-b,b)else
g(b,a)
for(c<-(5 to 629);
a<-(1 to c-2);
b<-(a to c-1);
if((a*a+b*b==c*c)&&g(c,g(a,b))==1)&&a<400)println(a+"  "+b+" "+c)
```

Ungolfed:

```
def gcd (a: Int, b: Int) : Int = if (a == b) 
  a else 
    if (a > b) gcd (a-b, b) else
      gcd (b, a)

def gcd (a: Int, b: Int, c:Int): Int = gcd (c, gcd (a, b))

def pythagorean (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = (a * a + b * b == c * c)

for (c <- (5 to 629);
  a <- (1 to c-2); 
  b <- (a to c-1);
  if (pythagorean (a, b, c) && gcd (a, b, c) == 1)) yield {
    println (a + "² + "  + b + "² = " + c + "² => " + (a*a) + " + " + (b*b) + " = " + (c*c))
    c*c
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL (31)

```
↑{(2×⍵),(A-1),1+A←⍵×⍵}¨2+2×⍳100
```

It uses basically the same approach as the Python program.

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB 29

```
i=2:2:200;[2*i;i.*i-1;i.*i+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mathematica 33**

```
{2#,#^2-1,#^2+1}&/@Range[4,203,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 26 chars, 52 bytes

```
{k(4×⍵),2+k←¯1+×⍨2×⍵}¨⍳100
```

test:

```
  a←{k(4×⍵),2+k←¯1+×⍨2×⍵}¨⍳100
  ≢a
100
  +/{(x y z)←⍵⋄(z*2)=(y*2)+x*2}¨a
100
  +/{∨/⍵}¨a
100
  10↑a
3 4 5  15 8 17  35 12 37  63 16 65  99 20 101  143 24 145  195 28 197  255 32 257  323 36 325  399 40 401
```

Answer (score 0):

### R, 49 characters

translated from the Python solution:

```
i=4;while(i<203){print(c(2*i,i*i-1,i*i+1));i=i+2}
```

Comment: You should take advantage of the functional nature of R `i=seq(2,200,2);c(2*i,i*i-1,i*i+1)` (though the output is a bit messy).

Comment: Ops! I posted without taking a look at all the other answers! :-P